# How to correctly handly NSError** pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nserror

What is the correct way to handle NSError** pointers?

```
- (BOOL)handleData:(NSDictionary *)data error:(NSError **)error {
    // pass the error pointer to NSJSONSerialization
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:options error:error];

    // Check if NSJSONSerialization had errors
    if (error)  // <-- sometimes this works, sometimes it crashes...
       return false;

    ...

    return true;
}

- (void)someMethod {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL result = [self handleData:dataDict error:&error]; 

    if (error) {
       // an error occurred
    } else {

    }
}
```

In this example `someMethod` passes a `NSError` reference to `handleData:error`. This is done by passing a pointer/address instead of the object (`...error:&error`)

The method `handleData:error` then passes this pointer to `dataWithJSONObject:options:error` (now without the `&`). Now I would like to check an error occurred, but what is the correct way to do this?

```
if (error)...   
// This works if error == nil. However this is not always the case. 
// Sometimes error is some address (e.g. 0x600001711f70) and *error == nil
// from the start of the method (passing error to NSJSONSerialization has no 
// influence on this

if (*error)...
// This works in cases where error itself is not nil, but it crashes if
// error == nil
```

Why is `error == nil` in some cases and `error != nil` but `*error == nil` in others?

**What is the correct way to pass error between the methods and to check if an error occurred?**

Comment: `Sometimes error is some address (e.g. 0x600001711f70)` - well, duh. You passed a pointer to your NSError* to the method, and it wrote the error information to it.

Comment: No, as explained `error != nil` is sometimes the case right after entering `handleData:error`, BEFOR passing error to `dataWithJSONObject:options:error`. Even if `error != nil` is true, `*error` is still nil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to find the answers is [Introduction to Error Handling Programming Guide For Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH201-SW1). The conventions are:

1. A method may return an `NSError` object via an `NSError **` parameter, such a method should also have a non-`void` return type and indicate success or failure via its return value. So, using your example, `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` will return `nil` if it encounters an error and *may* return an error object via its third parameter.
2. Any method accepting an `NSError **` parameter for error returns should accept either the address of an `NSError *` variable **or** `NULL`. The latter value means the user does not wish to have an error object returned. This means that the method accepting an `NSError **` parameter **must** check the parameter value is not `NULL` before attempting to assign an error object via it.

So your method `handleData:error:` must be prepared to accept `NULL` and needs to test for it. Your code therefore must include something similar to:

```
// Check if NSJSONSerialization had errors
if (jsonData == nil)
{
   // Error occurred, did it return an error object?
   if (error != NULL && *error != nil)
   {
       // we have an error object
   }
   else
   {
      // we have an error but no error object describing it
   }
}
else
{
   // no JSON error
}
```

HTH